# Running Android emulator on computer with AMD processor

Tags: java, android, emulation, amd-processor

Is there anyway to run Android virtual devices through Eclipse while operating with AMD processor? I had Genymotion for a while and despite it worked, it was too much of a kerfuffle to dabble with it.

Answer (score 32):

For **AMD** processor, create a new Virtual Device and while selecting the system Image select the ABI as **armeabi** instead of the default x86 one.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer, Basically If you don't have Intel processor and Your Processor is AMD then follow this answer and  you should make new virtual device by selecting armeabi-xxx

Comment: It is what it is.  Felt obligated to but needed a watch to develop on.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an Intel processor to run the emulator, it's just so much faster with the HAXM technology which obviously is not available to you.  I recommend buying a cheap Android device for testing, as none of the emulations provided with the ADK are particularly fast.

With developer mode enabled on your Android device, you'll find the debugging and all other useful features that Eclipse provides work very well (but note that developer features are now quite hidden: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/android-4-2-developer-mode-is-a-tricky-thing-heres-how-its-done/ ).

Comment: The problem is that my computer doesn't seem to run the virtual devices at all through Eclipse, no matter which devices and settings on VDs. With Genymotion, in few minutes, but with Eclipse, I managed to wait two freaking hours and just the glimmering Android screen. I don't know is it because of AMD processor or not. 

But yeah, I better try that device method, luckily I have few of those (too accustomed for running everything on computer :B ).

Comment: Try `bluestacks`. It is used mainly for games running on Android, but it is perfect and fast for Android development

Answer (score 1):

Use Genymotion insted of default one. It is way faster than the default one. And yaa the emulator is compatible with both Intel and AMD. Genymotion just uses Virtualbox to run Android in VM.

[Genymotion Home Page](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: Is there away it boots Genymotion straight from Eclipse? The last time I used it (albeit, a while ago), it was pretty darn kerfuffle to use with Eclipse.

Comment: Yaa you can ... but before that you need to start the VM from Genymotion. After that it works just like a device. You can directly run from eclipse.