# How to fix the 'VT not supported' error? Tried everything

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to use Android Studio and not having haxm installed is preventing the emulator from working.
I've tried many solutions to try and install it without getting the error 'VT not supported'. I have enabled Virtualisation Technology on the BIOS, looked for a Windows feature called 'Hyper-V' to uncheck however my pc does not seem to have this and other options such as installing oracle virtualbox, disabling 'hardware assisted virtualisation' on AVAST and countless restarts. Any help is appreciated. I'm using Windows 8.1 and amd processor. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried downloading haxm directly from Intel? That solution worked for me. There was a problem with the version I was getting from the SDK Manager.

Comment: AMD processor means you can't use HAXM - use Genymotion http://stackoverflow.com/a/26154647/295004

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use HAXM because it's only for Intel processors:

> The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a
>   hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel
>   Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT) to speed up Android app
>   emulation on a host machine. In combination with Android x86 emulator
>   images provided by Intel and the official Android SDK Manager, HAXM
>   allows for faster Android emulation on Intel VT enabled systems.

You should try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), it supports VT-X and also AMD-v.