# Error: Your cpu does not support required features(vt-x or svm) on AMD CPU under Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, android-studio-2.0, amd-processor

I keep getting the error noted above when I try to run a virtual device.

My CPU does support virtualisation and it is enabled.

I have ran a virtual device on eclipse before but, for some reason, Android Studio is giving me a hard time.

My CPU is an AMD FX 6350 six core processor 3.90 Ghz running Windows 10.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154373/running-android-emulator-on-computer-with-amd-processor

Comment: Enable it also during booting your computer

Comment: I did double check in my bios and it is enabled.

Comment: When i  went other  the other images tab with armeabi-v71 option   its says under recommendation  your cpu does not support requried features (VT-X pr SVM) consider using X 86 system image  on a X 86 host for better emulation performance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor?rq=1

Comment: Check my answer in this question it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475012/i-am-getting-this-error-your-cpu-doesnt-support-vt-x-or-svm-android-studio-2/42053205#42053205

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Android Studio emulator won't run on Windows with an AMD processor. The error message is kind of misleading, as it suggests the problem is with the CPU. But it is within the troubleshoot message: "Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor".

Solutions could be installing Linux and running Android Studio on that (which might come with its own issues), using a physical device for testing or using the slow ARM images.

Comment: What slow ARM images? I would use any image I could find that would work, but ALL available images in Android Studio say "your cpu does not support requried features (VT-X pr SVM)".

Comment: @PhilGoetz Under "Virtual Device Configuration" -> "Other Images" there are images titled "arm64-v8a" or similar. Do you get the same error with those? I can no longer thest it, I don't run Windows anymore.

Comment: Melanie's comment is important: the warning message is still shown when selecting "arm64-v8a" image, but it actually works

Answer (score 3):

Now, in 2019, Android Studio supports running virtual devices with AMD processor on Windows.

More info at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Prerequisites:

- AMD processor with virtualization (most do support it)
- enabled virtualization in UEFI/BIOS
- Windows 10 with Windows Hypervisor Platform (available from April 2018 Update, does **not** have to be Pro, can be Home)
- Windows Hypervisor Platform must be turned on
- updated Android Studio
- Android Emulator must be installed in SDK Tools

If any of these is missing the error message shown is misleading and recommends using an Intel processor or Linux, which is not very helpful.