# I am getting this error "your cpu doesn't support vt-x or svm, android studio 2.1.1 in AMD 6300 processor"

Tags: android, virtualization, android-studio-2.1

I have enabled the virtualization in bios setup but when i try to launch the emulator i am getting the error "your cpu doesn't support vt-x or svm"

I have installed Intel haxm too.

Comment: I forgot to mention its a windows 7 PC with 8 gb ram. everything else works fine except the emulator

Answer (score 11):

**2nd Aug 2019**

I am using AMD RYZEN 3400G. Got the same issue and i fixed it in a very easy manner.

> You have to enable **Windows Hypervisor Platform**

Go to *Control Panel> Programs > Turn Windows features on or off* and check the **Windows Hypervisor Platform**. And yes don't install HAXM.

---

**EDIT : 27th Aug 2019**

Only install the emulator image which is stable (or one version behind). For now use **Android P** image not Q, since I had a problem where Android Q image was not working with **HyperV** & only looking to install HAXM (which we know is not possible since it is not Intel)

> Note : The image **must not** be installing HAXM along with it, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to find this post again to tell you how much I love you. I have been at this for days messing with the BIOS settings, Hyper-V, and even trying to install a third party emulator. This solved my issue instantly. :)

Comment: @hisoka I am very glad this helped you :)

Comment: Android Emulator needs to be installed in SDK Tools too, otherwise same unhelpful error message pops up.

Comment: This really help accelerate my android emulator with my AMD Ryzen 5 2400G CPU to start up just 30 seconds (Pixel 2 API 28 - Android Pie image not Q)

Answer (score 8):

The VT-x technology as well as the HAXM are unique to Intel processors. In the case of AMD processors, AMD-V is the counterpart in the virtualization tech front. Installation of HAXM in an AMD processor will not have any impact and hence the error "your cpu doesn't support vt-x or svm".

Reference link: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator

As stated in the link above

> For best performance with Android Emulator 2.0, your system should
>   meet the following specifications: Windows: Intel® processor with
>   support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable
>   (XD) Bit functionality. AMD and Intel Atom processors do not support
>   VT-x virtual machine acceleration. Linux: Intel® processor with
>   support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable
>   (XD) Bit functionality or AMD processors with support for AMD
>   Virtualization™ (AMD-V™) 64-bit Operating Systems.

I would suggest to use an ARM image for the emulator instead of an Intel image. This would not require the use of HAXM nor VT-x.

Comment: This is incorrect. According to Android Studio's ADK manager, all of the ARM images require support for VT-x.

Comment: This is correct.  Downloading an ARM image allows you to continue with AVD setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to track this down myself for a while (very similar setup, but Windows 10), and haven't seen anyone offering a solution beyond "You know HAXM's just for Intel, right?" either. The best info I've found so far is that the "Individual" edition of [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) (free for personal use) seems to be the best bet for emulation on AMD chips, and, almost hidden, [a mention in the official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#accel-vm) that suggests Android Studio only works with SVM on Linux. I'm not even sure I'm reading the latter right, given the complete lack of references elsewhere to what should be an important fact, but it could be why that error is showing up – though if that's the case, it's definitely poorly worded.