# Error while using emulator on android studio

Tags: android

I am getting this error while using emulator:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Your CPU does not support
>   required features (VT-x or SVM).

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475012/i-am-getting-this-error-your-cpu-doesnt-support-vt-x-or-svm-android-studio-2

Answer (score 0):

HAXM is for Intel processor, for AMD you need to create a new Virtual Device in the ADB manager and select the ABI as armeabi-v7a instead of x86. Hope it works for you.