# My CPU doesn't support VT-x or SVM, and I need to emulate Android

Tags: android, android-studio, hardware, compatibility, emulation

My CPU doesn't support VT-x or SVM, and I need to emulate Android. Do I have any options? (Running Elementary OS 0.4.1, Dual-Core Intel Pentium CPU B940 @ 2.00GHz) Any help would be greatly appreciated, I own no mobile devices but I need to be able to post to Instagram to do my after-school job as a Social Media Monkey. I am currently attempting to use Android studio, but literally any other method of emulating Android, iOS, etc would be great.

Comment: https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try these links
[I am getting this error "your cpu doesn't support vt-x or svm, android studio 2.1.1 in AMD 6300 processor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475012/i-am-getting-this-error-your-cpu-doesnt-support-vt-x-or-svm-android-studio-2)
https://www.quora.com/Can-we-run-an-Android-emulator-on-a-PC-with-a-processor-that-does-not-support-VT-x

Also, look for options like bluestacks or youwave. See if gean
ymotion works for you.