# How to enable hardware acceleration for Android Emulator in Windows Server 2019?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have an AMD CPU, with Windows Server 2019 (dont ask why), where I enabled Hyper-V. However, in my (stable channel) Android Studio, it still says

> Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
>   Here are some of your options:
>
> 1) Use a physical device for testing
>
> 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
>
> 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
>
> 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
>      (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

Is it that the Hyper-V enabled emulator option only available in the beta channel of Android Studio? How to enable hardware acceleration for Android Emulator in Windows Server 2019?

Comment: posible duplicate see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475012/i-am-getting-this-error-your-cpu-doesnt-support-vt-x-or-svm-android-studio-2

Comment: @Mihai not a duplicate - since then, Android Emulator received support of Hyper-V, not so at the time of that post.

Comment: did you read this https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html

Comment: what version of android studio and emulator do you use? What AMD CPU does it suport AMD-V, SVM ?

Comment: I used both latest stable and latest beta. Ryzen 3 is my CPU and I enabled SVM through UEFI. Do see my answer below, it worked after running a command in PowerShell.

Comment: for AMD cpu on windows you need need WHPX and it seems windows server 2019 does not suport it read here about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/

Comment: WHPX is supported in Win Server 2019, though you have to enable it through PowerShell. Read my answer to this question.

Comment: I saw it now, nice that you found the answer it might help other people as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After an hour of searching, I've found that `Hyper-V` and `Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX)` are not the same. While you can enable `Hyper-V` through GUI in Windows Server 2019, you can't do the same for `WHPX`. Aside from enabling Virtualization in BIOS and `Hyper-V` through the GUI mode, to enable `WHPX` on Windows Server 2019 (and possibly other Server editions), run the following command in PowerShell with elevated permissions:

```
Dism /Online /Enable-Feature:HypervisorPlatform
```

It is working after running the command, even without a restart.