# CPU does not support VT-x or SVM (Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.)

Tags: android-studio

I have been trying to build some app with my laptop through the help from Android Studio. But before I am able to create a new virtual device (running the emulators), the system told me that "Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)".

However, when I use CMD to check, it show that Virtualization Enabled in Firmware = yes. Thus, what exactly is VT-x or SVM? How should I do to be able to continue writing for app.

MY PROCESSER : AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 
MY SYSTEM : Windows 10 
LAPTOP BRAND: LENOVO YOGA 530-14ARR

Comment: VT-x and SVM are other features that you need to enable **in addition** to the main "enable virtualization" switch in your computer's BIOS/UEFI Setup screen. "VT-x" is for Intel, SVM is for AMD.

Comment: plz look this Link or you can enable virtualization in BIOS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475012/i-am-getting-this-error-your-cpu-doesnt-support-vt-x-or-svm-android-studio-2