# Android studio Waiting for Target Device to Come Online

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, kernel, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.3

**Android Virtual Device (AVD) can't start .all SDK package removed and re-install again but still same issue ,Intel atom-x86 package installed , additional driver used for Radeon G-Card , VT-X is enabled via Bios setup , Virtual device created using qvga and software graphic emulator , trying with all android platforms . Error Details : GUI --> Waiting for Target Device to Come Online terminal -->timeout after 300 seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Emulator SDK folder removed manual and installed again via SDK Manager, abd killed and started again , studio is running as a root ,

using ----> AMD-A8 16G RAM

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried the answer in this post?
[Running Android emulator on computer with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154373/running-android-emulator-on-computer-with-amd-processor)

This states that you have to use the **armeabi** ABI instead of the default x86 one since you're running on a AMD processor.

Comment: i'm using now Genymotion and it's working fine , but i need to run AVD

Comment: Ok, I also wanted to suggest it but didn't because Genymotion isn't free. However, have you tried using my suggestion from the provided link?